# Query table for null columns when column name like

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle table which contains columns labelled attribute1 to attribute15.  I need to list any of those columns that contain any values.

I need to do something like;

```
select ... 
from table 
where column_name like 'attribute%' 
  and column is not null
```

Can't find anything resembling this

Comment: That sounds like the wrong database design.

Comment: Please show the exact definition of the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name He is probably using the Oracle e-Business Suite.  Almost every table in that database has at least 15 ATTRIBUTE* columns.  They're called "descriptive flexfields" and are actually very sensible and useful, especially for a database design that is 25+ years old.

Comment: Exactly right @MatthewMcPeak it's EBS.

Answer (score 1):

Why get fancy?

Describe your table to find out how many ATTRIBUTE* columns there are and then write this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  ATTRIBUTE1 IS NOT NULL
OR     ATTRIBUTE2 IS NOT NULL
OR     ATTRIBUTE3 IS NOT NULL
...
```

Or, if you need to know which columns in particular have values,

```
SELECT DECODE(COUNT(ATTRIBUTE1),0,'N','Y') ATTRIBUTE1_HAS_VALUES,
       DECODE(COUNT(ATTRIBUTE2),0,'N','Y') ATTRIBUTE2_HAS_VALUES,
       ...
FROM   TABLE;
```

Comment: I know there are 15 attribute columns, I just wondered if there was a way to wildcard the attribute column rather than write it out 15 times.  It's lazy I know, but if I have to do this discovery on multiple tables I'd like to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: There is no simple syntax for that.  You can use dynamic SQL to write the queries and execute them.  Depending on how well you know how to use dynamic SQL and how many tables you are analyzing, that may or may not be less work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have null values in most of the columns and need any non null values.

If aforementioned is correct understanding then you can use `coalesce` function as following.

```
Select coalesce(attribute1, attribute2, .... , attribute15) as val 
-- or use select * , if you want all columns value
From your_table
Where coalesce(attribute1, attribute2, .... , attribute15) is not null;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: It's more than likely that all the columns will be null, so yes it would be great to list any of them that have a value.  To avoid listing all 15 columns is my main goal here

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the table statistics to get this information.

1. analyze the table without sampling (= full)

   ```
   exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname=>user, tabname=>'TAB',estimate_percent=>100);
   ```
2. query the `NUM_DISTINCT` column in `user_tab_columns`

   ```
   select COLUMN_NAME, NUM_DISTINCT, NUM_NULLS
   from user_tab_columns 
   where table_name = 'TAB';

   COLUMN_NAME                    NUM_DISTINCT  NUM_NULLS
   ------------------------------ ------------ ----------
   ATT1                                      0          9
   ATT2                                      3          3
   ATT3                                      9          0
   ```

Note that `NUM_DISTINCT = 0` means that all values are `NULL`.

On the contrary `NUM_NULLS = 0`  identifies `not null` columns.